# Youngest Player to beat a reigning World Champion?

Tags: records, world-championship

In September 2022 19 year old [Hans Niemann beat Magnus Carlsen in the Sinquefield Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlsen%E2%80%93Niemann_controversy).

On the 19th January 2023 18 year old [Nodirbek Abdusattorov beat Magnus Carlsen in the Tata Steel tournament](https://twitter.com/ChesscomLive/status/1616143570276319232).

Is Abdusattorov the youngest player to beat a reigning world champion in a classical (i.e. not rapid or blitz) over-the-board game?

Comment: Youngest player to beat a World n°1 is probably 15yo Teimour Radjabov in Linares, but Garri Kasparov wasn't World Champion anymore at that time.

Comment: I am guessing that in the spirit of the question, simultaneous exhibitions are also excluded, right (or, rather, it is limited to tournament setting classic format only)? I've looked up pre-modern (~<1990) games and it'd seem that there were not just a lot of opportunities to young players to play a reigning champion, Fischer was notably fuming when he was denied to play Botvinnik. Also, not sure if relevant, but I would assume disputed situations like post-Alekhine's death interregnum and 1993-2006 split championships are treated permissively.

Comment: @Lodinn Yes, simuls don't count. As a 16 year old I drew with Kortchnoi in a simul. When a strong GM is playing 25 or more players at the same time then 1 or 2 will get lucky. It doesn't mean much, although a draw meant that I got my entry fee back which did mean a lot to a poor working class lad. Between Alekhine and Botvinnik there was no world champion. During the PCA time there were usually two world champions.

Comment: Still pretty impressive. Completely distracted IMs (at least, some of them) would usually handily beat me (~2000-2100) in my youth without even trying, so I reckon ratings matter quite a lot in chess. And for winning I would have to get *really* lucky, this is yet another ballpark entirely.

Answer (score 18):

I have not identified the record with certainty, but here are some young winners of World Champions in classical chess:

- N.Abdusattorov, 18y 4m 1d, [vs](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=2457584) Carlsen in Wijk aan Zee 2023
- V.Kramnik, 18y 8m 11d, [vs](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1070706) Kasparov in Linares 1994.
- A.Esipenko, 18y 9m 17d, [vs](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=2021289) Carlsen in Wijk aan Zee 2021
- T.Radjabov, 18y 11m 10d, [vs](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1397157) Topalov in Linares 2006

*Edit*: V.Keymer, [winning](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=2555769) against World #1 at 18y, 9m, 25d, would be in a very good spot on this list, had Magnus Carlsen not renounced his World Champion title a few months earlier...