# Who is the oldest player ever to beat a reigning world champion?

Tags: records, world-championship, trivia

Per title. I'm interested in all time controls. This record isn't in the Wikipedia [list of Chess records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess#Age-related_records).

Related: [Youngest Player to beat a reigning World Champion?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41393/youngest-player-to-beat-a-reigning-world-champion) which asks for the youngest player.

Comment: [classical, rapid, blitz but only regular open chess not women's, women's WFRCC or open WFRCC right?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33832/what-are-all-the-world-chess-championships-such-that)

Comment: Yeah, the question is about the world champion, not the women's world champion (although that could be a natural follow-up question).

Comment: Start with Korchnoi and then work yourself up (in age) :-)

Comment: Specifically, my best search result [age 63] was https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1038811

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best I could find:

- Former World Champion Emanuel [Lasker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Lasker) at 67 years, 8 months, 1 day [defeating](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1008303) Max Euwe in Nottingham (1936).